bijection map of LLM
I just want to know: could we built a bridge or bijection mapping for AI agent between Prompt and Response? In other words, AI can probabilistically generate a response based on our input prompt but does the procession irreversible?

No, but it's not a problem of LLMs. It can't happen with any system that gives you answers. The problem is inherently mathematical. Even if we had a deterministic function that associates an answer to a question, it would not be injective, so it would not admit an inverse.
I can make a simple example, but more intricate ones exist. This is a conversation with ChatGPT 4o:

Me: What is 2*2? Just give the answer, no other text
ChatGPT: 4
Me: What is 2+2? Just give the answer, no other text
ChatGPT: 4

So, "4" could be the answer to more than one (actually infinite) question, meaning that you can not find the question starting from the answer "4".

This is also the problem with the ultimate answer "42", because we can't work out what question it answers.

Thanks. Of course, I understand this "many-to-one" problem, 4 = 2*2 = 2+2 = 2³ - 2². Let’s dive into your conversation further. It seems like you’re connecting two disjoint sets through ChatGPT’s "mapping." However, keep in mind that what I’m talking about leans more towards embedding the prompt set into the response field. In other words, ChatGPT generates a result based on your question, and this functional consists of both the prompt and the answer, which together form the response. What I’m asking is, could we probabilistically return (guess) some characteristics of prompt?

Motivation of this question is the curious about AIGC checker.
